# regex count in single match

Tags: regex

I want to check if string doesn't have more than 5 numbers.  I can do it this way:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher(val);
i = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    i++;
}
```

However I would like to do it without while (because we are using regex validation framework).
I want to be able to match strings like

`A2sad..3f,3,sdasad2..2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex matches strings containing a max of 5 digits:

```
^(\D*\d){0,5}\D*$
```

And if you want to match strings consisting of exactly 5 digits, do:

```
^(\D*\d){5}\D*$
```

Note that inside a java.lang.String literal, you'll need to escape the backslashes:

```
boolean match = "A2sad..3f,3,sdasad2..2".matches("(\\D*\\d){0,5}\\D*");
```

or:

```
boolean match = "A2sad..3f,3,sdasad2..2".matches("(\\D*\\d){5}\\D*");
```

and you don't need to add the "anchors" `^` and `$` since Java's `matches(...)` already does a full match of the string.

Comment: I think this is what the author wants. He just wants to make sure there isn't _more_ than 5 digits.

Comment: I'd change (\D*\d) to use non-capturing group though. It's a bit more faster (although it's almost negligible).

Comment: @01, yes, that's why I said *"a max of 5 digit"*. If you need to match exactly 5 digits, replace `{0,5}` with `{5}`.

Comment: @reko_t, yes, since it is most probably negligible, I omitted it in favour of readability.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
^\D*(?:\d\D*){0,5}$
```

`\d` is a single digit and `\D` is the complement to that, so any character except a digit. `(?:…)` is like a normal grouping except its submatch cannot be referenced.

This regular expression allows any non-digit characters at the start, followed by at most five sequences of a single digit followed by optional non-digit characters.

Comment: @Bart K.: What makes you think that? It’s semantically equivalent to yours.

Comment: @Bart K.: it'd match 0-4 digits as well. There's a \D* at the beginning.

Comment: thanks, i choose to accept Bart K. because its the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use negative look-ahead:

```
^(?!(?:\D*\d){6})
```